# What's the strongest non-ML chess engine?

Tags: engines

What's the current strongest Chess Engine built solely on heuristics, no neural networks or any kind of deep learning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strongest classical chess engine is probably Stockfish classical, i.e. Stockfish with its NNUE turned off. I say this because Stockfish was leagues ahead of all its CPU rivals before the NNUE revolution, and after the NNUE revolution very few people are still working on classical engines, so it's unlikely anyone caught Stockfish. In fact, if you look at [CCRL](http://ccrl.chessdom.com/ccrl/4040/) (Computer Chess Rating Lists), no classical engine has caught Houdini (all the engines above it are either NN or NNUE based).

Comment: What's Houdini?

Comment: @theonlygusti a chess engine - https://www.cruxis.com/chess/houdini.htm. Do note Houdini is controversial, because it's allegedly [a Stockfish clone](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29181/is-houdini-6-a-stockfish-clone).

Comment: So by saying no classical engine has caught Houdini, you are saying that Stockfish is the strongest classical engine

Comment: Houdini is currently the strongest classical chess engine, but it is just a weaker version of what pre-NN stockfish used to be?

Comment: @theonlygusti Stockfish classical is significantly stronger than Houdini, and no classical engine has caught Houdini, let alone Stockfish classical.

Comment: Houdini is arguably an older version of Stockfish classical, in particular Stockfish 8. The last version of Stockfish classical was somewhere after Stockfish 11 but before Stockfish 12.